# Login adfs in java and get assertion from saml response

Tags: java, adfs

I am trying to connect `adfs` in java native application. There are some problems when access `saml response` after successful authentication into adfs.

1. url connect with `jsoup`

   - `https://<fqdn>/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignOn.aspx?`
   - `loginToRp=urn:amazon:webservices`
2. fill username and password and post data
3. after successfully login getting context data
4. post context data to `fqdn mfa` (multi factor authentication)

I am getting login page again but `not saml response`

Comment: You need to include some source code in the question if you want a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the ADFS configuration.

IdpInitiatedSignOn.aspx?loginToRp=urn:amazon:webservices implies that:

- urn:amazon:webservices is the identifier of a RP
- The RP needs to be built on top of the SAML protocol
- The reply URL needs to be configured to the SAML ACS (the method expecting the token) of your app.

Is this what you have done?

What Java SAML stack are you using?